# Динамический SQL запрос с определением таблицы по условию

Tags: sql, oracle

Задача связана с использованием динамического SQL в БД Oracle.

В схеме присутствует таблица `MAIN` с двумя колонками: `CODE` и `TABLE_NAME`. В столбце `TABLE_NAME` перечислены названия всех остальных таблиц в схеме, в столбце `CODE` - уникальный код для каждой таблицы.

Необходимо создать динамический запрос/процедуру, которая будет 
принимать на вход значение `CODE`, определять по нему `TABLE_NAME` и выполнять

```
SELECT * FROM имя_найденной_таблицы
```

Пробовал "собирать" запрос как строку `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` по примерам в гугле, но, к сожалению, безрезультатно. Топик на англоязычном SO также не помог.

Comment: При такой постановке задачи это невозможно. любой запрос должен вернуть на клиента результат с заранее определенной структурой. В процедуре вы конечно можете сделать и вернуть курсор из `select *` только на клиенте вы его обработать не сможете опять же не зная структуру заранее. Так что поясняйте, зачем надо выполнять запрос с неизвестным заранее набором столбцов, что вы хотите получить в результате такого выполнения

Comment: Поясню на примере Клиента. Клиенту известен только уникальный CODE. Он вводит его на странице, после чего он должен увидеть данные из таблицы, которая соответствует этому уникальному коду. То есть, необходимо 1) Определить TABLE_NAME по тому CODE, который ввел Клиент. 2) Выполнить 'SELECT * FROM эта_таблица' и отобразить Клиенту данные.

Comment: Сделайте это двумя запросами, первый получает имя таблицы, второй выполняет селект из нее. т.е. динамическое формирование запроса делайте на клиенте

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```sql
create table main as
    select 'code'||rownum code, trim (column_value) tableName 
    from xmlTable ('"hr.employees","hr.departments"');

create or replace procedure getResultSet (code varchar2) is
    tn main.tableName%type;
    cur sys_refcursor;
begin
    select tableName into tn
    from main 
    where code=getResultSet.code;
    open cur for 'select * from '||tn;
    dbms_sql.return_result (cur); 
end;
/
```

Запуск и результат:

```sql
exec getResultSet ('code2')

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME                MANAGER_ID LOCATION_ID
------------- ------------------------------ ---------- -----------
           10 Administration                        200        1700
           20 Marketing                             201        1800
           30 Purchasing                            114        1700
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Для данной задачи даже какой-то ЯП не нужен, достаточно написать небольшой скрипт в клиенте. SQL в клиенте всегда динамический.

Например в SQL*Plus:

```sql
SQL> create table main as
    select 'code'||rownum code, trim (column_value) tableName 
    from xmlTable ('"hr.employees","hr.departments"');
SQL> col tableName new_value tableName noprint
SQL> select tableName from main where code='&code';
Enter value for code: code2

SQL> select * from &tableName;

DEPARTMENT_ID DEPARTMENT_NAME                MANAGER_ID LOCATION_ID
------------- ------------------------------ ---------- -----------
           10 Administration                        200        1700
           20 Marketing                             201        1800
           30 Purchasing                            114        1700
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот такая ужасная конструкция работает в MySQL :

```
set @t=(select tname from maint where code='001'); set @s=concat("select * from ",@t); PREPARE stmt FROM @s; EXECUTE stmt;
```

Простое решение типа:

```
select * from (select tname from maint where code='001')
```

не работает - возвращает просто имя таблицы, но не её содержимое.

Без двух запросов Вам никак не обойтись.

Comment: А при чем тут MySQL ?

Answer (score 0):

Я немного преобразовал имеющийся в документации пример запроса:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm

Получилась такая процедура (сам проверить не могу, нет под рукой сервера Oracle, так что проверять и отлаживать придется вам):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE select_from_table (pCode NUMBER) IS
   v_table   VARCHAR2(30);
   sql_stmt  VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN

  SELECT TABLE_NAME INTO v_table FROM MAIN
    WHERE CODE = pCode;
  sql_stmt := 'select * from ' || v_column;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt;
END select_from_table;
/
```

Comment: `SELECT TABLE_NAME INTO v_table FROM MAIN WHERE CODE = code;` При использовании такой конструкции, а именно `CODE = code` могу возникать поразительные ошибки! Лучше изменить имя параметра `code => pCode`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, спасибо, прозевал при переписывании )